# How do i pass the ID of row to Modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have Edit button on each row. If I press Edit button on selected row I need pass ID of this row to Modal and use it in sql query to call rest of data. P.S. I tried many ways, no one of them helped and based on bootstrap.

Here is my code with Modal

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Müştərinin Nömrəsi</th>
        <th>Götürülən Ünvan</th>
        <th>Gədilən Ünvan</th>
        <th>Zəng Vaxtı</th>
        <th>Sürücünün Tabel Kod</th>
        <th>Təhfil aldı</th>
        <th>Təhfil verdi</th>
        <th>Maşın Nömrəsi</th>
        <th>Qiymət</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php


while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)) // цикл вывода
{
 $id = $data['id'];

     
  echo "<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>".$data['MUSHTERINOMRE']."</td>
        <td>".$data['MUSHTERIHARDAN']."</td>
        <td>".$data['MUSHTERIHARA']."</td>
        <td>".$data['ZENGVAXTI']."</td>
        <td>".$data['TABELKOD']."</td>
        <td>".$data['TEHFILALDI']."</td>
        <td>".$data['TEHFILVERDI']."</td>
        <td>".$data['MASHINNOMRE']."</td>
        <td>".$data['QIYMET']."</td>
        <td><button class=\"btn btn-success\" onclick='getValue(".$id.");' data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" contenteditable=\false\" value=".$id.">EDIT </button></td>
  "; ?>
            
      </tr>
   
   <?php
}
   ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="">?   </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>

                <!--Here I am trying to echo ID
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php //echo $id."ID OFaa"; ?></h4>-->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
   <?php echo $id."I NEED TO GET ID HERE "; ?>
   <?php 
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'psw');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('my_db', $link);

   $query = mysql_query("Select * from my_table where id = $id");
   //var_dump($pt);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   $number = $row['num'];
   ?>
         <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Müştəri Nömrə:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num" name="num" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                  </div>
   
   
   
   
   </div>
   
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From what I can understand from your question, you want to pass the ID from javascript to PHP?  If that's true then it's not possible, unless you make an AJAX call.

Comment: To do this, fire an AJAX request to a PHP script with your ID and show the response in modal

Comment: I have php and html only in my code and button onclick is not working well,so i need change my edit button for working one,

Comment: Can you show me an example please?  Or maybe show on my code

Comment: Have posted the answer, do let me know if you still face problems

Comment: There are 9 fields. How many do you want to edit?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I need to edit 8 of 9.  Column 'Zəng Vaxtı' is working on sql back end. It takes current time.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Could you advice me smth?

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov, work got in the way today. I'll see if I can post something later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing to remember is that PHP won't execute client-side, so populating the dialog with id and editable values must be performed by the client-side language - javascript. Your only option for further server-side involvement during the editing process is to make AJAX call(s).

You will find the process a lot simpler with a "promisified" modal dialog. Rather than write something yourself, you can install install, [bootStrapModal](https://github.com/keatec/bootStrapModal), giving you a modal that is much like the standard Bootstrap modal but behaves as an asynchronous resource.

HTML:

```
<script src="js/bsBetterModal.js"></script>
```

Build the table rows as follows :

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // цикл вывода
    $id = $data['id'];
    echo "<tr data-id=\".$id.\">
        <td></td>
        <td class=\"mushterinomre\">".$data['MUSHTERINOMRE']."</td>
        <td class=\"mushterihardan\">".$data['MUSHTERIHARDAN']."</td>
        <td class=\"mushterihara\">".$data['MUSHTERIHARA']."</td>
        <td class=\"zengvaxti\">".$data['ZENGVAXTI']."</td>
        <td class=\"tabelkod\">".$data['TABELKOD']."</td>
        <td class=\"tehfilaldi\">".$data['TEHFILALDI']."</td>
        <td class=\"tehfilverdi\">".$data['TEHFILVERDI']."</td>
        <td class=\"mashinnomre\">".$data['MASHINNOMRE']."</td>
        <td class=\"qiymet\">".$data['QIYMET']."</td>
        <td><button class=\"btn btn-success edit\">EDIT</button></td>
    </tr>";
} ?>
...
```

Write the dialog's header as follows :

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="">?   </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title dlg-element" data-element="id"></h4>
</div>
```

Write each of the dialog's inputs (x8) as follows :

```
<label class="control-label">Müştəri Nömrə:</label>
<input type="text" class="dlg-element" data-element="mushterinomre" value="" />
```

Write the dialog footer as follows :

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ok">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

The EDIT buttons' click handler is a little complicated. It comprises some preamble followed by a promise chain. I've made it as simple as I can by unloading the fiddly bits into a bunch of helper utilities.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // *** start: click handler ***
    $('#myTable').on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // in case button attempts form submission
        var $button = $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var idHash = { 'id': $row.data('id') }; // <<<<<< HERE'S THE ID - expressed as a js plain object.
        // From here on, everything is asynchronous, therefore performed within a promise chain.
        fetchValues(idHash) // Fetch current values (onscreen values may be stale)
        .then(function(valuesHash) {
            return betterModal.run($('#myModal'), $.extend(valuesHash, idHash))// Open modal window, populated with current field values.
            .then(function($dialog) {
                // The dialog was accepted.
                // `$dialog` holds a jQuery object of the dialog.
                return saveValues($.extend(dialogToHash($dialog), idHash)); // Pass hash of editable field values, plus idHash, to saveValues()
            })
            .then(function() {
                // New values were successfully saved.
                // valuesHash is still in scope
                updateHtmlTableRow($row, valuesHash); // Update the HTML table row with the edited values.
            }, function(err) {
                // Save failed
                // Provide warning to user ...
                return err;
            })
        })
        .then(null, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            $button.prop('disabled', false);
        })
        .always(function() {
            $button.prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
    // *** end: click handler ***

    var fields = ['mushterinomre', 'mushterihardan', 'mushterihara', 'tabelkod', 'tehfilaldi', 'tehfilverdi', 'mashinnomre', 'qiymet']; // 'zengvaxti' omitted

    // *** start: helper utility functions ***
    function fetchValues(idHash) {
        return $.getJSON({
            'url': 'api.php', // replace with actual url
            'method': 'get',
            'data': idHash
        });
    }
    function saveValues(values) {
        return $.ajax({
            'url': 'api.php', // replace with actual url
            'method': 'put',
            'data': values
        });
    }
    function dialogToHash($dialog) {
        var hash = {};
        fields.forEach(function(f) {
            hash[f] = $('.'+f, $dialog).val();
        });
        return hash;
    }
    function updateHtmlTableRow($row, valuesHash) {
        fields.forEach(function(f) {
            $('.'+f, $row).text(valuesHash[f]),
        });
    }
    // *** end: utility functions ***
});
```

Untested and sketchy in places so will need debugging. Some server-side stuff also needs to be addressed.

Comment: Dear Roamer. I did all these changes and my Edit button stop working. What i did wrong?

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov, I don't know without seeing your revised code. Maybe you could publish a link to a demo - codepen or similar.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Orik3ll0/uxefe4h8/1/
here is it, I do not understand where I should write jquery script and in what should i write in second php file

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this gives you some direction**

```js
function getValue(id)
{

$.ajax({
url:'filename.php',
method:'get',
data:'id='+id,
success: function(ret)
{
// add the returned value into the modal body
$('#modalBody').html(ret);
// show the modal
$('#myModal').show();

}
});

}
```

Comment: For "Edit" functionality, `modal ---> ajax` would make more sense than `ajax ---> modal`.

Comment: Thanks, would really appreciate if you could provide an example

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go.

Comment: @RohitBandooni Than you for an example. I added this to script, and created new php file lets name it 'filename.php' in that file i added: `<?php
$p=$_GET['id'];
?>` than in modal i do `var_damp($_GET)` and getting same id for every Edit: `array(1) { ["p"]=> string(1) "1" }`

Comment: @RohitBandooni I just see that  `array(1) { ["p"]=> string(1) "1" }` it is my pagination data. It is not from script. How make it work?

Comment: @RohitBandooni Can you advice me something?